# how to add VC++ 2015 x86 and x64 as a dependencies in UWP package?

Tags: c#, visual-c++, uwp, windows-10

How to add prerequisites in my UWP app .. I want to install VC++ 2015 as dependencies of my UWP APP

I am not going to understand how to add my VC++ 2015 X86 and X64 in the package file... 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145

```
 <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" 
      MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
  </Dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please right click on the `Reference` in the project and select `Add Reference`.

Select `Universal Windows`, then search *visual C++*. You will find the reference, you can select it and add to your project.

[image: 33ba4bf7-8044-4c6a-98fd-1bc86f75ea37.png]

Best regards.

Comment: this will install these VC++ 2015 https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145 ?

Comment: Hi, appears in the `Universal Windows` list is the installed reference. If you can't find Visual C++ 2015 here and the development tool you are using is Visual Studio 2015, you can try to download and install it.

Comment: from where i can download this VC++ 2015 Universal Windows

Comment: Which version of your Visual Studio? It is recommended that you use the latest version of Visual Studio for development. The Visual C++ package should be in the SDK package of the UWP development tool. You can open the `Visual Studio Installer` and try to install `C++ (v141)/(v142) Universal Windows Platform Tool`

Comment: I have small confusion this VC++ 2015 microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145  and Universal Windows Platform Tool VC++ 2015 are same ... i want this VC++ 2015 for my WPF App EXE which in under UWP app Win32 folder

Comment: This seems to be inconsistent with the question you asked. In the question, you want to know how to add a reference to Visual C++ 2015. But why add it to the WPF application? WPF does not need to add VC++2015 specifically, as long as it is installed on your computer.

Comment: I need VC++ 2015 microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145 in the UWP package.. that is my question..check my question title..I have to tokbox in my app and tokbox required the VC++2015... so i want how to add VC++2015 redistributable in my UWP APP

Comment: If you are using a desktop bridge to convert a Win32 application to a UWP application, you can refer to this [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/using-visual-c-runtime-in-centennial-project/) for VC++ configuration. I hope this can help you.